# Cant change color of confirm and cancel button of spinner datepicker android react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-spinner, android-appcompat, android-datepicker

This is what I've tried so far

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/spinnerDatePickerTheme</item>
   <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="spinnerDatePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
   <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/mySpinnerDatePicker</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">#404651</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="mySpinnerDatePicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker">
   <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
   <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/negativeButtonStyle</item>
   <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/positiveButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="negativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
   <item name="colorAccent">#404651</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="positiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
   <item name="colorAccent">#404651</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
</style>
```

I can change the default style of the android picker but when I try to change the style of the spinner, it won't work

Comment: which library are you using  for datepicker?

Comment: I'm using react-native-modal-datetime-picker which uses DatePickerAndroid